# How do I configure a Spring Batch job that executes/ is triggered when a flag is set or value is available from the Database

Tags: sql-server, spring, batch-processing

Possible Solution: Have two Spring jobs. One job is a scheduled one that runs every 15 mins and reads the value from the DB table. The second job is triggered "on demand" that is when the flag value is available.

I'm not sure how much feasible this solution is.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried that solution?